# Error message of "Use of unresolved identifier 'vImage_Buffer'"

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

I just need to swizzle the bytes of a .bgra8Unorm texture into RGBA order and create a `UIImage` from the data. I create a buffer as follows.

```
var buffer = vImage_Buffer(data: data, height: UInt(height), width: UInt(width), rowBytes: bytesPerRow)
            
let map: [UInt8] = [2, 1, 0, 3]
vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(&buffer, &buffer, map, 0)
```

But I am getting error messages

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'vImage_Buffer'"
>
> "Use of unresolved identifier 'vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888'".

I have already imported `MetalKit`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: `vImage` functions and types are defined under Accelerate framework. Do you have `import Accelerate`?

Comment: Thanks you OOper.I just imported.

Answer (score 4):

Just put

```
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
```

as commented by @OOPer

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 version:

```
import Accelerate
```